# c++ XOR between bitsets

Tags: c++, xor, operation, std-bitset

```
std::bitset <1> a1;
std::bitset <1> a2;

a1 = std::bitset<1> (0);
a2 = std::bitset<1> (1);

std::bitset<1> b = (a1 ^= a2)
```

This results in

```
b = 1
```

which is fine but modifies also a1, which after the XOR operation becomes:

```
a1 = 1
```

Why is this happening?
How can I avoid this without creating *temp* variables?

Comment: Well it *should* modify `a1` since what you're doing with `a1 ^= a2` is actually equal to `a1 = a1 ^ a2`.

Comment: Use `^` instead of `^=`.

Comment: Are you sure `a2` changed?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the code does a bit of wheel-spinning. Instead of creating your bitset objects then assigning to them from temporary objects, just initialize them with the appropriate values: `std::bitset<1> a1(0); std::bitset<1> a2(1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::bitset <1> a1;
    std::bitset <1> a2;

    a1 = std::bitset<1>(0);
    a2 = std::bitset<1>(1);

    std::bitset<1> b = (a1 ^ a2);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << a1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << a2 << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

**Correct output:
1
0
1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::bitset <1> a1;
    std::bitset <1> a2;

    a1 = std::bitset<1>(0);
    a2 = std::bitset<1>(1);

    std::bitset<1> b = (a1 ^= a2);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << a1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << a2 << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

**Correct output:
1
1
1**
because `^=`, so you change a1.

XOR is operator `^`

Operator `^=` is XOR with assignment

Answer (score 1):

```
  std::bitset<1> b = (a1 ^= a2);
```

You are modifying `a1` here as

`a1^=a2` is equivalent to `a1=a1^a2`.Also it will only modify `a1` and not `a2`.

Use this

```
  std::bitset<1> b = (a1 ^ a2);
```

Answer (score 1):

in line : std::bitset<1> b = (a1 ^= a2) , you are using nested equation.

if u will simplyfy the rhs you will get -> a1 = a1^a2, so you are first assigning a1 = 0 xor 1 i.e. 1 and then you are assigning b with a1 that's why you are getting a1 = 1 also, along with b.

for more explanation you can refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm (directly go to the assignment operators section.)